# App freeze while Schedule LocalNotifications in background

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, uilocalnotification

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    for (int i =0; i<30; i++){
       //add a local notification and schedule it
    }
}
```

when app switch to background, these codes will freeze app in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no document about UIApplication is thread safe or not.
After a long time test I found most time execute `LocalNotification` on background works well. but some times it just crash our app.

So it seems like all the class with 'UI' prefixed are not thread safe and you should never invoke there's methods on another thread.

And my solution is reduced the number of `LocalNotification`, it still freeze app in a bit, but we thing we can accept this little freeze.

Answer (score 1):

By default, application processing freezes when the app goes to the background. The execution continues from the same statement where it left when the app comes back to the foreground. To execute code in the background, you have to surround it in the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` block.

Have a look at the section **Completing a Finite-Length Task in the Background** at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html.

Comment: I spends lots of time to test and now i'm sure you can't play `localNotification` on background thread :D